# Two background images. One in HTML one in BODY. In Firefox body image isnt rendered

Tags: html, css

Something weird is happening.

I've a basic html code. html, head, body.
(As I've received some negative votes, here's the full code)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
html {
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-top:-8px;
}
body {
    background-image: url(telefonillo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

This is what chrome and firefox shows:
[image]

How can I fix this?

I tried to "Inspect" with firefox, and tried to remove the "background.png" from HTML, then the "telefonillo.png" shows up.

Tried "z-index:1" on body, but isn't working, as it isn't content at all.

Edit: I also tried removing all the divs, and other css, incase there was some kind of problems between any rules, but it's still happening.

Comment: How do you want it to look like? What do you want to achieve? Can we see a jsfiddle.

Comment: Basically I want to both background images show up. As title says, both images arent shown with Firefox.

Comment: Without code it's impossible to analyze, but have you floated the elements after the body or something like that?

Comment: Confirmed weirdness in FF 18.0.2: http://jsfiddle.net/N9d5u/

Comment: Was about to upload jsfiddle but @Chad came out with it.
@SvenBieder the code is: `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use before like this

```
body:before {
    content:"";
    background:url(background.png) no-repeat top left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    background:url(telefonillo.png) no-repeat top left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: You may need to set a z-index on this depending on what image is in front

Comment: Tried. Not working. Even tried to Z-Index both. Before and itself.

Comment: Solved it. But by setting 100% height and 100% width to Body.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to add the following tags inside the head of the html document:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Anyway, this has helped me with weird issues like this in the past.  I hope it helps someone out there!